# How to track redirections between ASP.NET MVC projects?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, redirect

I have a complex legacy solution. In some place (which I'm unable to find) there's a redirection from one web project to another. I can't locate calling method using stack trace because it's broken by the redirection.

Is there any way to find caller (a particular method in the solution) of some action method?

On the other hand - what approach to solving this kind of problem would you propose? I've "travelled" thousands lines of code but the line with redirection is really deep inside the structure...

Both web projects are ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: You can do the follwing search on Visual Studio: Edit->Fast Search and select the whole solution...search for Redirect or location.href

Comment: @Hackerman This isn't exactly the solution I'm searching for. There's too much of results which makes noise.

Comment: if you know the exact redirect url, you can nwrrow your search, right?, besides, when you swim into a dark pool of legacy code, you need to get a bit dirty :)

Comment: Not exactly. Redirect url must not be a plain url. It can be read from some configuration key for instance... But right, this kind of swimming makes one dirty ;).

Comment: I truly understand you my friend; i too swim on those waters about a month ago :)...Can those configuration keys be on the Windows Registry?, if so, you can check the accessed keys using the Process Monitor https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx

Comment: No, no, I've meant keys in .config files, but thank you :).

Comment: What about checking the referrer in the Http Headers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution. it's not an exact answer for a general question, but I believe it may help someone in the future, so I'm gonna leave this Q&A and not delete it.

Redirection in my case was done by Forms authentication. In case of using Forms authentication a redirection link can be placed in web.config.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
<forms loginUrl="/some/url" name="cookieName" />
</authentication>
```